# How to run a Explore and Search session/campaign?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-preparation

So I am planning on running a section of my campaign where the party has to enter a mulitlayers pit, where each layer is a plane with its own eco system, monsters and effects. It's 13 layers stacked on top of each other.

They have to find a specific location hidden on one of the layers (they dont know which one).

How would I run this session? Making the exploration of finding this location fun, rather than just a series of skill checks and clues?

Comment: You are describing a dungeon with 13 levels.  Each level has a different eco system.  Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: For those answering, please remember to support your answers with mechanics you've used or seen in this type of situation.

Comment: Do you want the players to traverse all 13 layers in one session? Or one session per layer?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Yes

Comment: @MikeQ Not necessarily, ill probally just take it as far as they can get per session. Im usually pretty good at pacing where we need to be. Also they don't need to go through all 13 layers. What they are looking for is somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Also, welcome to our stack (and great first question!) Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Are you not sure how to handle the exploration of the pit?  The biomes of the pit?  How to broadcast the objective's location to your players?  You're asking a very vague, open ended question that doesn't have one specific answer, so we need you to narrow it down a bit so we can better help.

Comment: @JRodge01 nails it. I think what the site really needs is what you imagine this adventure looking like: How do you expect the PCs to handle this adventure? Also, are you going to, like, hide the MacGuffin on layer 1 but make PCs explore all the layers anyway? Further, some effects will obviate this adventure (e.g. *commune*, *find the path*); have those been accounted for? Also, *I* would like to know if the planes are infinite, dangerous, inhabited, and so on.

Comment: @Rachen My suggestion would be to weave into question asking if there is a published module that has an Explore and Search theme. This will give you the answer you want, guidance and will be referenced.

Comment: @Orc'sPlunder By editing the question to ask for resources, my fear is then that, even if only weaved in, the question would veer into shopping territory (i.e. *Is there a published adventure that involves large-scale exploration?* yields an unbounded list) therefore remain on hold.